# Can LINQ based DataGridView's be "disconnected" from the LINQ expression?

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, datatable

I have a `DataView` created with `LINQ`, connected to a `DataGridView`. When I change values in the `DataGridView` the `LINQ` Expression is immediately executed and changea the result in my `DataView`.

Is there a way to `"disconnect" the  DataGridView from the LINQ script` to suppress the changes in the DataView?

```
void MyFunc()
{
    DataGridView myGrid;
    DataTable myTable;

    // filling the table

    // assigning the table to the grid
    myGrid.DataSource = myTable;

    // filtering DataTable with LINQ
    var filteredRows = (from DataRow in myTable.AsEnumerable() 
                        where (...) 
                        select (row));

    // assigning the result to the DataGrid
    myGrid.DataSource = filteredRows.AsDataView();

    ...
}
```

Comment: You mean: to defer the update? You actually want to update them but not now, don't you?

Comment: Try `CopyToDataTable` instead of `AsDataView`

Comment: Yes, I want to defer the update
@Daniel: I have to delete rows. When I use a copy of the table I have to to delete the rows in the orignial table manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute/Iterate your query and get a new DataTable using `CopyToDataTable` and then assign that as `DataSource`

```
var filteredRows = (from DataRow in myTable.AsEnumerable() 
                        where (...) 
                        select (row)).CopyToDataTable();
DateGridView.DataSource = filteredRows;
```

This will cause a temporary `DataTable` to be a source of your Grid and will be disconnected to your LINQ expression. 
Later you can get the `DataTable` from your `DataSource` and update.

Comment: I have to delete rows. When I use a copy of the table I have to to delete the rows in the orignial table manually.

Comment: @boboes, yes that is the cost you will pay for disconnected mode.

Comment: ok, so I will duplicate my fields used in the LINQ filter. The first are displayed and the others are hidden. The user changes the displayed fields and with an "update" button the visible fields are transfered to the hidden once and then the LINQ is executed. Seems for me better than manually synchronizing the tables. Thanks to all :)